# How do I design a database with one-to-one or one-to-many relationships for a column?

Tags: database-design, one-to-many, relationship, one-to-one

I am designing a database to store metadata about music.
For instance, I would store the following data:

```
Song      : A Year Without Rain
Album     : A Year Without Rain
Artist    : Selena Gomez & the Scene
Composers : Lindy Robbins, Toby Gad
```

...into these 5 tables:

```
Songs      : song_ID, songTitle, album_ID, artist_ID, composer_IDs
Albums     : album_ID, albumTitle
Artists    : artist_ID, artistName, performer_IDs
Performers : performer_ID, performerName
Composers  : composer_ID, composerName
```

The problem is, for a given song (song_ID), there could either be one or more more than composer (composer_IDs) associated with it. The same goes for the number of members (performer_IDs) in a band (artist_ID).

I don't want to use arrays or comma-separated values to store multiple values in these columns. How do I fix this problem?

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de/7296873) answer, but I couldn't figure out how to implement that with this design. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question sounds a lot like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437686/entity-relationship-diagram-entity-which-can-have-multiple-types).

Comment: Yes, that's very similar to this question, and makes things a little more clear. Thanks again for pointing me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another table called `Song_Composer`, containing two columns: `Song_ID` and `composer_ID`. Then you can associate as many composers as you like with each song by adding rows with the same song ID

Comment: That's pretty much the Many-to-Many relationships on the question you linked.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry about the stupid question. I guess I wasn't really thinking straight.

Answer (score 1):

Change the table structure and also add two tables `SongsComposers` & `ArtistsPerformers`

> Songs      : song_ID, songTitle, album_ID, artist_ID
>
> Composers  : composer_ID, composerName
>
> SongsComposers :song_ID,composer_ID
>
> Artists    : artist_ID, artistName
>
> Performers : performer_ID, performerName
>
> ArtistsPerformers :artist_ID,performer_ID

Comment: That's exactly what @squeamish-ossifrage suggested. Thank you for your input as well.